# Fabric's sudo('service httpd start') doesn't work

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, fabric

[1] I executed Fabric's sudo('service httpd start').

```
[chikaram] sudo: service https start
[chikaram] out: Starting httpd:                       [  OK  ]
```

[2] But my web page is still down!

[3] So I checked httpd status on EC2

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo service httpd status
httpd dead but subsys locked
```

[4] Then I started httpd on EC2.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd:                                       [  OK  ]

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo service httpd status
httpd (pid  25217) is running...
```

I've tried this many times but the results always same.

- Fabric's sudo('service httpd start') fails with message "httpd dead but subsys locked."
- "sudo service httpd status" on EC2 works.

So as of now, I'm doing like: local('ssh chikaram "sudo service httpd start"')

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem and resolved by below.

Here is my workaround.

```
sudo('service %s restart && sleep 5' % service,)
```

This program restart some service defined above(such as nginx) and wait 5 sec if service restart return code is zero.

I guess root cause is fabric session is shutdown before fork is not completed.